# Which of the following queries will use the index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

Given collection `foo` with the following index:

```
db.foo.createIndex( { a : 1, b : 1, c : 1 } )
```

We need to select which of the following queries will use the index?

1. `db.foo.find( { c : 1 } ).sort( { a : -1, b : 1 } )`
2. `db.foo.find( { b : 3, c : 4 } )`
3. `db.foo.find( { a : 3 } )`
4. `db.foo.find( { c : 1 } ).sort( { a : 1, b : 1 } )`

I'm surprised that **3**, **4** are correct options and **1**, **2** are not.

## Why is the following queries will use the index?

```
db.foo.find( { a : 3 } )
```

This seems to be able to use the index however `_id` is not projected out.

```
db.foo.find( { c : 1 } ).sort( { a : 1, b : 1 } )
```

We're looking for `c` which is on the **right side** of the index

## Why is the following queries will "not" use the index?

```
db.foo.find( { c : 1 } ).sort( { a : -1, b : 1 } )

db.foo.find( { b : 3, c : 4 } )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query 1**

```
db.foo.find( { c: 1 } ).sort( { a: -1, b: 1 } );
```

Filtering with `{ c: 1 }` will not use the index, since `{ c: 1 }` is not the prefix of `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }` ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes)). Sorting with `{ a: -1, b: 1 }` will not use the index, since sort direction (1 or -1) does matter ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields)).

**Query 2**

```
db.foo.find( { b: 3, c: 4 } );
```

Filtering with `{ b: 3, c: 4 }` will not use the index, since `{ b: 1, c: 1 }` is not the prefix of `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }`.

**Query 3**

```
db.foo.find( { a: 3 } );
```

Filtering with `{ a: 3 }` will use the index, since `{ a: 1 }` is the prefix of `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }`.

> This seems to be able to use the index however _id is not projected
>   out.

Field `_id` will be in the result of the query, unless you specify the contrary.

For document `{ _id: 1, a: 3, b: 4, c: 5 }` consider the next queries and their results

```
> db.foo.find( { a: 3 }, { _id: 0, a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 } );
{ "a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 5 }
> db.foo.find( { a: 3 }, { a: 1 } ).explain("executionStats");
...
"executionStats": {
    "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
    ...
> db.foo.find( { a: 3 } );
{ "_id": 0, "a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 5 }
> db.foo.find( { a: 3 } ).explain("executionStats");
...
"executionStats": {
    "totalKeysExamined": 1,
    "totalDocsExamined": 1,
    ...
```

Note that in second case document's `_id` was fetched from the collection (`"totalDocsExamined": 1`) after the index scan, since the query does not say that `_id` field is not required in the result.

**Query 4**

```
db.foo.find( { c: 1 } ).sort( { a: 1, b: 1 } );
```

Sorting with `{ a: 1, b: 1 }` will use the index, since `{ a: 1, b: 1 }` is prefix subset of `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }` (for non-prefix subset - see [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields)) and sort keys are listed in the same order, direction as in the `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }` ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields)). Though, the index will not be used for filtering, since `{ c: 1 }` is not the prefix of `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }`. Consider the next queries and their results

```
> db.foo.find( { c: 1 }, { _id: 0 } ).sort( { a: 1, b: 1 } ).explain("executionStats");
...
"executionStages": {
    "stage": "FETCH",
    "filter": {
        "c": { "$eq": 3 } // filtering is done by fetching from the collection
    },
    "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "indexBounds": {
            "a": [ "[MINKEY, MAXKEY]" ],
            "b": [ "[MINKEY, MAXKEY]" ],
            "c": [ "[MINKEY, MAXKEY]" ] // index was not used for filtering c
        }
        ...
> db.foo.find( { a: 1 }, { _id: 0 } ).sort( { a: 1, b: 1 } ).explain("executionStats");
...
"executionStages": {
    "stage": "PROJECTION",
    "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "indexBounds": {
            "a": [ "[3.0, 3.0]" ],      // index was used for filtering a
            "b": [ "[MINKEY, MAXKEY]" ],
            "c": [ "[MINKEY, MAXKEY]" ]
        }
        ...
```

Note that in second case both filtering and sorting were done using the index and there were no call to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the first question: db.foo.find( { c : 1 } ).sort( { a : -1, b : 1 } )

The direction matters, you have here more information
[why does direction of index matter in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329104/why-does-direction-of-index-matter-in-mongodb).

And you can take a look to http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf => page 56

In relation to the second. The order of keys defined in an index does matter too.
Here more information => [Mongodb query - Does sequence of key matters in usage of compound index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977943/mongodb-query-does-sequence-of-key-matters-in-usage-of-compound-index)